# Counting the value of an element from array of object and store the result to new element

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, object

I would like to count the value in the element then add an element called "Count".
Condition: count the quantity if the next element is the same "Quantity" value then add the result to new element called "Count". I'm trying to do this using a for loop function, but my code didn't go well.

Here my data.

```
let myData = [
                {
                    Name: 'Section 1', 
                    Details:[
                        { Product: 'Ballpen', Quantity: 120},
                        { Product: 'Pencil', Quantity: 120},
                        { Product: 'Marker', Quantity: 80},
                        { Product: 'Highlighter', Quantity: 120}
                    ]
                },
                {
                    Name: 'Section 2', 
                    Details:[
                        { Product: 'Paper', Quantity: 40},
                        { Product: 'Bond Paper', Quantity: 75},
                        { Product: 'Colored Paper', Quantity: 75},
                        { Product: 'Oslo paper', Quantity: 40}
                    ],
                }
            ]
```

Expected Output:
My table will looks like this...

---

- PRODUCT   * Quantity * Count *

---

- Ballpen     *    120   *   2   *
- Pencil      *    120   *   2   *
- Marker      *    80    *   1   *
- Highlighter *    120   *   1   *

---

Meaning it will count every time the quantity value of the product will be the same value on the next element. Stop the counting even if there is still same value from other element but not the next element.

※ On the Console.log(). It will looks like...

```
Section 1 : {
                [ Product = 'Ballpen', Quantity = 120 , Count = 2],
                [ Product = 'Pencil', Quantity = 120 , Count = 2],
                [ Product = 'Marker', Quantity = 80 , Count = 1],
                [ Product = 'Highlighter', Quantity = 120 , Count = 1],
            },
Section 2 : {
                [ Product = 'Paper', Quantity = 40 , Count = 1],
                [ Product = 'Bond Paper', Quantity = 75 , Count = 2],
                [ Product = 'Colored Paper', Quantity = 75 , Count = 2],
                [ Product = 'Oslo paper', Quantity = 40 , Count = 1],
            },
//Other codes here...
```

I'm sorry, but i'm still learning on how to manipulate data, so thank you for your understanding. :)

Comment: The best I can gather is the console is asking whether it is supposed to be a multi dimensional array with each sub array named "product". Or are you trying to make object lierals?    https://medium.com/the-codehub/object-literals-and-function-constructors-in-javascript-87affed2d6b4

Comment: @Samuel Marchant, Thank you. the link you provide helped me to understand with this object literals and how to work with function constructors and prototype properties :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is what you are looking for

```js
let myData = [
                {
                    Name: 'Section 1', 
                    Details:[
                        { Product: 'Ballpen', Quantity: 120},
                        { Product: 'Pencil', Quantity: 120},
                        { Product: 'Marker', Quantity: 80},
                        { Product: 'Highlighter', Quantity: 120},
                    ]
                },
                {
                    Name: 'Section 2', 
                    Details:[
                        { Product: 'Paper', Quantity: 40},
                        { Product: 'Bond Paper', Quantity: 75},
                        { Product: 'Colored Paper', Quantity: 75},
                        { Product: 'Oslo paper', Quantity: 40}
                    ],
                }
            ]
            myData.forEach((ele, idx)=>{
                ele.Details.forEach((ele2, idx2)=>{
                    let value = ele2.Quantity;
                    let count = 0;
                    let sliced = ele.Details.slice(idx2, ele.Details.length)
                    let ok = true;
                    sliced.forEach(ele3=>{
                        if (ele3.Quantity == value && ok)
                            count++;
                        else
                            ok = false
                    })

                    ele2.Count = count;
                    if(typeof ele.Details[idx2 - 1] != 'undefined')
                    {
                        if (ele.Details[idx2].Quantity == ele.Details[idx2 - 1].Quantity)
                            ele.Details[idx2].Count = ele.Details[idx2 - 1].Count
                    }
                    
                })
            })
            console.log(myData);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).